# Using the Youtube Data API and the AP crashed

Tags: youtube-api

I have downloaded the sample code of the below path
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/143669/Manage-YouTube-using-C-and-Youtube-API-1-6

Then I have installed the YouTube_SDK_2.1.0.0.msi
Now I can build the project successfully, but when I want to search a video in the Youtube
the AtomFeed of the videofeed will return the `Error=NoLinkedYouTubeAccount`
Please tell me what happened, I already surveyed some days in network.

Sample code list as below

```
yousettings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("My AP", devkey, username, password);
yousettings.Credentials.AccountType = "GOOGLE";

.........

videofeed = yourequest.Get<Video>(new Uri(feedUrl));
```

videofeed will always return fail then the Sample Ap will be crashed, the crash info list as below:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   `Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException` occurred in
>   `Google.GData.Client.dll` Additional information: Execution of request
>   failed:
>   http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/top_rated?time=today

Note:

1. I have link the Youtube account to the Google account.
2. I try to modify the yousettings.Credentials.AccountType = "GOOGLE";
3. FeedUri = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/top_rated?time=today"